# Extending React Component in order to add Custom Fields?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

i'm trying to create a component that returns a `Flex` Element from [chakra-ui](http://next.chakra-ui.com/) , naturally i would like to keep the Auto Complete from the `Flex Type` when using my component but additionally i would like to add an extra prop to it called "iconName".

This is the code i wrote:

```
type TFlex = typeof Flex

const Tab: TFlex = ({ iconName, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Flex align="center" height="12" minWidth="12" {...props}>
      <Icon name={iconName} size="8" />
    </Flex>
  )
}

export default Tab
```

But doing so is yielding the following error:

[image]

From my understanding I would need to:

- Extend the `FlexProps Inteface` and call it MyFlexProps
- Extend the `Flex Type` and call it MyFlexType
- Type my `Tab` instance with MyFlexType

But unfortunately i could not make this work and also i'm not sure if that's the right approach?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this solved my issue:

```
interface ITab extends FlexProps {
  iconName?: string
}

const Tab: React.FC<ITab> = ({ iconName, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Flex align="center" height="12" minWidth="12" {...props}>
      <Icon name={iconName} size="8" />
    </Flex>
  )
}
```